# Flip Animation for Android Activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new to android app development.
I am doing a project where i get data from cursor object and display them on a screen.
When next and previous buttons are clicked respective data from cursor is displayed.
Now i am adding animation like page flip to that activity.
Only data changes in the activity.I need flip effect in the same activity itself by changing the data on it.
Can any one help..

Comment: Show your code. Also what API you are testing this animation on?

Comment: I am using Aphid-FlipView as API for animation